# C++: Error with MergeSort implementation with arrays: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): for

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

I'm working on an implementation of Merge Sort in C++, and I'm getting the following error when I run my MergeSort function:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./p1: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000001a250d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x386ce75e5e]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x386ce7a528]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x5c)[0x386ce7ab1c]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_Znwm+0x1d)[0x343febd0cd]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs4_Rep9_S_createEmmRKSaIcE+0x59)[0x343fe9c3c9]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs4_Rep8_M_cloneERKSaIcEm+0x2b)[0x343fe9d19b]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs7reserveEm+0x3c)[0x343fe9d5ec]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs6appendERKSs+0x4f)[0x343fe9dabf]
./p1[0x403b35]
./p1[0x401ef9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x100)[0x386ce1ed20]
./p1[0x401879]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00406000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 12322163                           /home/hmp54/p1b/p1
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 12322163                           /home/hmp54/p1b/p1
01a25000-01a46000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
343fe00000-343fee8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1062181                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
343fee8000-34400e8000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 1062181                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
34400e8000-34400ef000 r--p 000e8000 fd:00 1062181                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
34400ef000-34400f1000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:00 1062181                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
34400f1000-3440106000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
386ca00000-386ca20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6815797                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
386cc20000-386cc21000 r--p 00020000 fd:00 6815797                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
386cc21000-386cc22000 rw-p 00021000 fd:00 6815797                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
386cc22000-386cc23000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
386ce00000-386cf8b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6815808                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
386cf8b000-386d18a000 ---p 0018b000 fd:00 6815808                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
386d18a000-386d18e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 6815808                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
386d18e000-386d190000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 6815808                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
386d190000-386d194000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
386d200000-386d283000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6816160                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
386d283000-386d482000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 6816160                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
386d482000-386d483000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 6816160                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
386d483000-386d484000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 6816160                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3995800000-3995816000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6815780                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3995816000-3995a15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 6815780                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3995a15000-3995a16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 6815780                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f4654000000-7f4654021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4654021000-7f4658000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f465a4d0000-7f465a4d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f465a4e2000-7f465a4e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffeca062000-7ffeca077000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffeca13c000-7ffeca13d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
(OrderedList) After mergeSort: Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've declared the functions within an `OrderedList object`, and `myArray` from the following chunk of code is what I'm sorting: 
(`myArray` is an `int*`)

```
OrderedList::OrderedList(int size){
    theArraySize = size;
    myArray = new int[size];  
}
```

'MergeSort()':

```
void OrderedList::mergeSort(int first, int last){
    int middle; 

    if(first < last){
        int middle = ((first + last) / 2); 
        mergeSort(first, middle); 
        mergeSort(middle + 1, last);
        merge(first, middle, last); 
    }
}
```

Here is my 'Merge()' Function:

```
void OrderedList::merge(int first, int middle, int last){
    int tempArray[last];  
    int i = first, j = middle + 1; 
    int index = first; 

    while((i <= middle) && (j <=last)){

        if(myArray[i] < myArray[j]){
            tempArray[index] = myArray[i]; 
            i++;
        } else { 
            tempArray[index] = myArray[j]; 
            j++; 
        }
        index++; 
        theTraversalCount++; 
    }


    if(i > middle){
        while(j <= last){
            tempArray[index] = myArray[j];
            j++;
            index++;  
            theTraversalCount++; 
        }
    } else{
        while(i <= middle){
            tempArray[index] = myArray[i]; 
            i++;
            index++;
            theTraversalCount++; 
        }
    }

    for(int k = first; k < index; k++){
        myArray[k] = tempArray[k];
        theTraversalCount++;  

    }
}
```

I'm still new to using pointers (I've really only worked with java before c++, so pointers still aren't that intuitive to me) so I'm wondering if I might have done something wrong with my array declarations/array pointer declarations?

Comment: Note that VSA is not supported in C++

Comment: What is VSA? @Slava

Comment: Sorry its VLA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard. Btw such errors usually happen due to out of bounds memory access or violation of rule of three https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) but without [mcve] it is quite impossible to say what is wrong

Comment: `int tempArray[last];` -- This is not valid C++.  Also, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c)

Comment: Step through with a debugger, and you might notice that you write to `tempArray[last]` on the last iteration, which is beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Also, if you instead used `std::vector` instead of pointers and non-standard VLA's, you would have had a better chance of figuring out the error, since `std::vector` has an instant debugging function called `vector::at()` that would have checked the array boundaries.   Using `tempArray.at(index)` would have thrown an `out_of_range` exception right when you tried to access the element at `index`.  Using pointers and/or VLA's, you don't have these facilities available to you.  Think of it like Java's stack trace when you make an out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the project is for my data structures class, and so my professor doesn't allow us to use vectors. I'll keep this in mind for when I can use vectors, though

Comment: @hmp54 You could have prototyped your solution first by using vector to see if it works.  Once you had it working, then you change to the type that the teacher wants you to use.  Also, I would think it is strange that you couldn't use `vector`, which is part of standard C++ but allowed to use non-C++ such as variable length arrays.